# How to print register address in GDB?

Tags: gdb

I want to print the register's own address where it resides in memory using GDB.
For example, Where does the GPG register r1 reside in memory?
From the result below I can't find the register's own address.

```
(gdb) info reg r0 r1
r0             0x0  0
r1             0x0  0
```

even with

```
(gdb) x/x $r0
0x0 <_ftext>:   0xffffffff
(gdb) x/x $r1
0x0 <_ftext>:   0xffffffff
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Registers don't have addresses, only names.  They are locations in the CPU itself, not in RAM.